# Is it possible to download and upload recordstore and images by using CommConnection?

Tags: java, mobile, java-me

I want to know if it is possible to `download` from a computer server or to `upload` to a computer server the `recordstore data` and `images` of a J2ME application by using the `CommConnection` connection ( using cable ). Is it possible ? If it is possible , how to make the computer server know that it should treat the received data when I upload the data from the J2ME application ? Because I want to insert and update these recordstore data into a MySQL database in the computer server.

For the `download` how to make the computer server know that I want to get just some pieces of data from the MySQL database and some photos from the computer filesystem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to write an app on your PC which also listens on the com port.  Then you will need to make up a simple data protocol that meets your needs.  You'll find the [`DataInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/io/DataInputStream.html) and [`DataOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) classes pretty useful for this.

As you are writing your mobile app in Java, you may find [JavaCOMM](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/Serial_Java) meets your needs for writing the server end.